# How can I update all records from a source db table to a target db table using spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch program that pulls data from a source DB to a target DB once a day. In the case that a record is updated on the source DB side. How can I detect that and update my target DB?

Comment: Which database are you using? There may be existing options for synchronizing, but without knowing which database technology is in use it is harder to present an answer.

Comment: The source is DB2 and the target it oracle.